# MongoDb stopping again and again

Tags: database, mongodb, schema

I'm trying to make a node-mongo application on a digital ocean basic server (1GB mem, 25GB SSD, 1vCPU). The mongo server crashes again and again.

This is the mongo log file just before crash

[image]

Through looking at the logs and doing some research I've found that multiple slow queries are causing this server overload triggering the stopping of mongod.

The mongoose query is as follows

```
  // Get a batch of external links in each iteration
  const externalLinkObjs = await linkSchema
    .find({}, { _id: 1, domainId: 1, externalLink: 1, isHidden: 1 })
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(this.filterLimit);
```

linkSchema

```js
    const linksSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    domainId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'domains'},
    articleId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'articles', index: true},
    externalLink: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 4},
    rel: {type: String, required: true, default: "dofollow"},
    anchorText: {type: String, trim: true, default: ""},
    isHidden: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    status: {type: Boolean, default: false}
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Is there a way to optimize this query?

Comment: What is the number of docs? if you run `find({}).itcount()` or similar. What I would do, at first, is to move reads to a secondary node.

Comment: Provide the logs as text.